# How can I make a while loop keep incrementing while ascending

Tags: c++

```
int range;
int i = 1;

cout << "Enter number range:";
cin >> range;

while (i <= range){
    cout << i << endl;          
    ++i;
```

What I have in mind

Enter number range: 5

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Run a nested loop to print each line `for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: A `for` loop would make more sense for your current `while` loop. As in `for (unsigned i = 1; i <= range; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: Yep, using while loop made no sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observer carefully, this will be solved using 2 loops instead of 1.

```
int range = 5;
    for (int i=1;i<=range;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<i+1;j++){
        cout<<j<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
```

Comment: @Rednuht Note that it's not the *wrong* loop per se, both `while` and `for` are semantically equivalent. The problem is you only had one loop, while you needed a pair of nested loops.